# Glicko 2 rating deviaton during inactivity

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to use [glicko 2 rating system](http://www.glicko.net/glicko/glicko2.pdf) in my software. The document mentions that when a player does not compete during a "rating period" the deviation $φ$ is updated using this formula:

$$
φ' = \sqrt{φ^2 + σ^2}
$$
For example if a "rating period" is one month and a player has φ=50 and σ=0.06(the recommend value) after 10 years(120 "rating periods") of inactivity φ will be 124.646889.

However, this means that it takes 10 years(120 rating periods, assuming one rating period is one month) for deviation to increase from 50 to 124.646889. What if I would like to keep the same rating period(one month), but I would like deviation to increase more rapidly? I think Glicko1 had some constant that could adjust this. I cannot find a similar constant for Glicko2. It has to be some way, otherwise the algorithm would be quite constraining.